# phpMailer форма обратной связи

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, форма, phpmailer

Есть форма которая отправляет данные введенные пользователем на почту. Библиотека phpMailer. Вот код:

```
<?php 

require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

$name = $_POST['user_name'];
$phone = $_POST['user_phone'];

$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                                                                                             // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'test@gmail.com'; // Ваш логин от почты с которой будут отправляться письма
$mail->Password = 'testpassword'; // Ваш пароль от почты с которой будут отправляться письма
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587; // TCP port to connect to / этот порт может отличаться у других провайдеров

$mail->setFrom('test@gmail.com', 'name'); // от кого будет уходить письмо?
$mail->addAddress('test@gmail.com');     // Кому будет уходить письмо 
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Кто-то оставил форму обратной связи!';


$mail->Body = '<b>' .$name . '</b> оставил заявку, его телефон <b>' .$phone. '</b>';
$mail->AltBody = '';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo '<b>Не удалось отправить заявку :(</b><br>Позвоните нам!';
} else {
    header('location: index.html');
}
?>
```

Вопрос, как сделать при успешном выполнении кода, вывод попапа с помощью js/jQuery.
Например тут:

```
else {
        header('location: index.html');
    }
```

И наоборот вывод попапа с ошибкой.
Спасибо за внимания!